# How can I restore the data from a deleted Group

Tags: groups

Scenario is - contacts had been added to a Group (in this case for subsequent deletion) but a user then incorrectly deleted the Group, rather than the contacts in the Group.

Answer (score 1):

Achieved this via SQL

Step 1. Identify contacts who the log_civicrm_group_contact table shows were added to the group (and who are not now in Trash, since we can add Trashed contacts to a Group) with a query that includes the value of the new group they will be added to (in this case 893) and filters for the Group that was deleted (764)

> select 893, contact_id, log_civicrm_group_contact.status
> FROM log_civicrm_group_contact
> LEFT JOIN civicrm_contact cc ON cc.id = log_civicrm_group_contact.contact_id
> WHERE group_id = 764
> AND status = "Added"
> AND log_action = "Insert"
> AND cc.is_deleted = 0
> ORDER BY contact_id;

Then we grab the result as an SQL insert as follows

> INSERT INTO `civicrm_group_contact` (`group_id`, `contact_id`, `status`)
> VALUES

with rows like

> (893, 76639, 'Added')

Note we ORDERED by contact_id as we had too bit a sql insert so it got cut off, and by ordering by id we could rerun the insert scrip for those which got dropped from previous run.